# Python pip fails but packages are installed

Tags: python, numpy, build, scipy, pip

I'm trying to install `scipy` in a Python [virtualenv](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv):

```
$ virtualenv venv
New python executable in venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)$ pip install scipy
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-0.16.1.tar.gz
Collecting numpy>=1.6.2 (from scipy)
/home/kramer65/zommel/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Building wheels for collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scipy
  Complete output from command /home/kramer65/zommel/venv/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-6oiqvO/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpdmYP0Hpip-wheel-:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-6oiqvO/scipy/setup.py", line 253, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-6oiqvO/scipy/setup.py", line 241, in setup_package
      from numpy.distutils.core import setup
  ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.core

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for scipy
Failed to build scipy
Installing collected packages: numpy, scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy
Successfully installed numpy-1.10.1 scipy-0.16.1
/home/kramer65/zommel/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

This output first says `Failed to build scipy` after which it says `Successfully installed numpy-1.10.1 scipy-0.16.1`, which I don't understand.

Does anybody know why it fails and succeeds at the same time?

Comment: Did you tried installing from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/?

Comment: Only the creation of a wheel failed. After realizing this, pip apparently decided to build from the setup.py file.

Comment: What is a wheel?